# How to create textures within GPU

Tags: opengl, textures

Can anyone pls tell me how to use hardware memory to create textures in OpenGL ? Currently I'm running my game in window mode, do I need to switch to fullscreen to get the use of hardware ?

If I can create textures in hardware, is there a limit for no of textures (other than the hardware memory) ? and then how can I cache my textures into hardware ? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to create texture objects or the data for textures?

Comment: Hey again, I mean is there a way to cache the texture DATA in GPU, other than sending all the data of the texture when we need to draw it ?

Answer (score 3):

This should be covered by almost all texture tutorials for OpenGL. For example [here](http://www.nullterminator.net/gltexture.html), [here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=06) and [here](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Tutorial_Framework:Texture_Mapping).

For every texture you first need a texture name. A texture name is like a unique index for a single texture. Every name points to a texture object that can have its own parameters, data, etc. [glGenTextures](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenTextures.xml) is used to get new names. I don't know if there is any limit besides the uint range (2^32). If there is then you will probably get 0 for all new texture names (and a gl error).

The next step is to bind your texture (see [glBindTexture](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindTexture.xml)). After that all operations that use or affect textures will use the texture specified by the texture name you used as parameter for glBindTexture. You can now set parameters for the texture ([glTexParameter](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml)) and upload the texture data with [glTexImage2D](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) (for 2D textures). After calling glTexImage you can also free the system memory with your texture data.

For static textures all this has to be done only once. If you want to use the texture you just need to bind it again and enable texturing (glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)).

The size (width/height) for a single texture is limited by GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE. This is normally 4096, 8192 or 16384. It is also limited by the available graphics memory because it has to fit into it together with some other resources like the framebuffer or vertex buffers. All textures together can be bigger then the available memory but then they will be swapped.

In most cases the graphics driver should decide which textures are stored in system memory and which in graphics memory. You can however give certain textures a higher priority with either [glPrioritizeTextures](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPrioritizeTextures.xml) or with glTexParameter.

**Edit:**
I wouldn't worry too much about where textures are stored because the driver normally does a very good job with that. Textures that are used often are also more likely to be stored in graphics memory. If you set a priority that's just a "hint" for the driver on how important it is for the texture to stay on the graphics card. It's also possible the the priority is completely ignored. You can also check where textures currently are with [glAreTexturesResident](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glAreTexturesResident.xml).

Comment: i have done all of those myself other than glPrioritizeTextures. But thanks for your time for explaining it with details.about your last words, that is the thing I was asking... to force the texture to be store at graphics memory rather than let the driver deciding ?? glPrioritizeTextures, is it the only way to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you talk about generating a texture on the **GPU**, you're not actually creating texture images and applying them like normal textures. The simpler and more common approach is to use Fragment shaders to procedurally calculate the colors of for each pixel in real time from scratch for every single frame.
The canonical example for this is to generate a Mandelbrot pattern on the surface of an object, say a teapot. The teapot is rendered with its polygons and texture coordinates by the application. At some stage of the rendering pipeline every pixel of the teapot passes through the fragment shader which is a small program sent to the GPU by the application. The fragment shader reads the 2D texture coordinates and calculates the Mandelbrot set color of the 2D coordinates and applies it to the pixel.

Fullscreen mode has nothing to do with it. You can use shaders and generate textures even if you're in window mode. As I mentioned, the textures you create never actually occupy space in the texture memory, they are created on the fly. One could probably think of a way to capture and cache the generated texture but this can be somewhat complex and require multiple rendering passes.

You can learn more about it if you look up "GLSL" in google - the OpenGL shading language.
[This somewhat dated tutorial](http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/mandelbrot_set_p4.php) shows how to create a simple fragment shader which draws the Mandelbrot set (page 4).
If you can get your hands on the book "OpenGL Shading Language, 2nd Edition", you'll find it contains a number of simple examples on generating sky, fire and wood textures with the help of an external 3D Perlin noise texture from the application.

Answer (score 1):

To create a texture on GPU look into "render to texture" tutorials. There are two common methods: Binding a PBuffer context as texture, or using Frame Buffer Objects. PBuffer render to textures are the older method, and have the wider support. Frame Buffer Objects are easier to use.

Also you don't have to switch to "fullscreen" mode for OpenGL to be HW accelerated. In fact OpenGL doesn't know about windows at all. A fullscreen OpenGL window is just that: A toplvel window on top of all other windows with no decorations and the input focus grabed. Some drivers bypass window masking and clipping code, and employ a simpler, faster buffer swap method if the window with the active OpenGL context covers the whole screen, thus gaining a little performance, but with current hard- and software the effect is very small compared to other influences.